# ubuntu one installation failure from the app centre

Tags: ubuntu-one

I'm trying to install Ubuntu one from the software center but when I'm trying to install it, it opens a page saying not found. is there any terminal command to install Ubuntu one?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One has been discontinued both according to the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_One) and according to [Canonical's own blog](http://blog.canonical.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/).